How to perform parallel testing with pytest and avoid conflicts with shared resources?
I’m using pytest for writing and running tests in my Python project. I need to perform parallel testing to speed up the CI/CD process. However, I’m facing issues with some tests conflicting due to the use of shared resources, such as the database and the file system.
I have tried using pytest-xdist for running tests in parallel, but I’m not quite sure how to properly isolate resources for each test. How do you solve issues with parallel testing in pytest? Are there any best practices or example configurations that can help avoid conflicts between tests?
I have tried the following approaches:
1.  Using pytest-xdist:
•   Installed pytest-xdist to enable parallel test execution using pytest -n <num_processes>.
•   Expected tests to run in parallel without interfering with each other.
2.  Isolating database for each test:
•   Created separate databases for each test to avoid conflicts.
•   Expected that tests accessing the database would not conflict.
3.  Mocking shared resources:
•   Used mocking libraries to simulate access to shared resources like file systems.
•   Expected that this would prevent conflicts over shared resources.

Despite these efforts, I am still experiencing issues where tests fail due to resource conflicts. For example, tests that involve database operations sometimes interfere with each other, causing data corruption or incorrect results.
I’m looking for best practices or configurations that could help mitigate these issues, ensuring reliable and conflict-free parallel test execution with pytest.
